# List of strings to one string

Tags: c#, string, performance, functional-programming

Lets say you have a:

```
List<string> los = new List<string>();
```

In this crazy functional world we live in these days which one of these would be best for creating one string by concatenating these:

```
String.Join(String.Empty, los.ToArray());

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
los.ForEach(s => builder.Append(s));

string disp = los.Aggregate<string>((a, b) => a + b);
```

or Plain old StringBuilder foreach

OR is there a better way?

Comment: Looks like .Net 4 will also include a string.Join(string, IEnumerable<string>), letting you skip the ToArray() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx

Answer (score 324):

I would go with option A:

```
String.Join(String.Empty, los.ToArray());
```

My reasoning is because the Join method was written for that purpose. In fact if you look at Reflector, you'll see that unsafe code was used to really optimize it. The other two also WORK, but I think the Join function was written for this purpose, and I would guess, the most efficient. I could be wrong though...

As per @Nuri YILMAZ without `.ToArray()`, but this is .NET 4+:

```
String.Join(String.Empty, los);
```

Comment: GA! I didn't even see this option at first- read right past it.

Comment: I did some tests and they showed that this was about three times faster than the StringBuilder, but both of these were much better than the aggregate

Comment: 3 times faster than the StringBuilder? Wow, I figured it would be faster, didn't realize just how much faster. It makes sense though, it's done in unsafe code using pointers, so..... makes sense.

Comment: nice! only remark: Join doesn't need los.ToArray(), because List<T> can cast IEnumarable<T>.

Comment: @Nuri: This question was asked in 08, before .Net 4 was out. The overload that takes IEnumerable<T> was added in .Net 4.

Comment: @BFree: I see, you are right! I did not care about posted date, I'm sorry.

Comment: String.Join in conjunction with String.Concat is golden. Ex: 'String.Concat( "{ ", String.Join( ", ", m_Data ), " }" );'

Answer (score 55):

```
string.Concat(los.ToArray());
```

If you just want to concatenate the strings then use string.Concat() instead of string.Join().

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 19):

If you use .net 4.0 you can use a sorter way:

```
String.Join<string>(String.Empty, los);
```

Answer (score 10):

String.Join() is implemented quite fast, and as you already have a collection of the strings in question, is probably the best choice. Above all, it shouts "I'm joining a list of strings!" Always nice.

Answer (score 10):

```
los.Aggregate((current, next) => current + "," + next);
```

Answer (score 5):

My vote is string.Join

No need for lambda evaluations and temporary functions to be created, fewer function calls, less stack pushing and popping.