# passing parameter to powershell script from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, c#-4.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to pass a list of strings as a parameter to powershell script.
That list may contain any number of argument varies every time. How do I pass this list as a one parameter to powershell script from C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell parameters are separated by commas. Just add the parameters comma separated behind the call.

**Edit after comment:**

Is it maybe possible to change the `List<string>` to a `StringBuilder` and after each add just add an additional ,?

If that is not possible try it like: [List of strings to one string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318756/list-of-strings-to-one-string)

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
los.ForEach(s => builder.Append(s+","));
```

Comment: @sebinel i want to pass list ,that is dyanamic list (LIST<String>)...this list as one parameter

Comment: ah okay. didn't get that from your question.