# Add Multiple items of a List to one line in another List

Tags: c#, list

Imagine I've this following `List`:

```
List<string> thirdList = new List<string> {"0","0","56'BCD"}
```

I need to add all of its items to a new list as one value i.e., `"0 0 56'BCD`. Please note that there is space between the items in the new string. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of strings to one string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318756/list-of-strings-to-one-string)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So you want a list with a single string? You can use `String.Join`:

```
var result = new List<string>{ String.Join(" ", thirdList) };
```